# Undefined symbol (CLSID_CMPEG2EncoderVideoDS)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, video, directshow, mpeg-2

I cannot compile my project, that uses MPEG2 DirectShow video encoder. I've included Wmcodecdsp.h, but when I compile project, Visual C++ gives undefined symbol error on CLSID_CMPEG2EncoderVideoDS. I've tried to add to project msmpeg2enc.dll, but linker can't link it doesn't have export table.

The error I get is about this:

> CaptureGraph.obj : error LNK2001: undefined external symbol "CLSID_CMPEG2EncoderVideoDS

Comment: Full/exact error message quote? Or we are supposed to guess?

Comment: Sorry, I have russian-translated Visual Studio, so, description may be not so exact. "CaptureGraph.obj : error LNK2001: undefined external symbol "CLSID_CMPEG2EncoderVideoDS""

Comment: Next time be sure to check [ask] and [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linker error like this means you need to link a missing `.LIB`

A search on Windows SDK `\lib` directory gets you `wmcodecdspuuid.lib`. Hence...

```
#pragma comment(lib, "wmcodecdspuuid.lib")
```

... some where on the source code (I prefer below `#include`s) will do the trick.